# Problem with get_the_title in <a href""> not rendering the way I want

Tags: get-the-title

It's quite hard to put a title on this question.
So the problem is if my page title is "BLA BLA" my href link will not work.

```
<a  href="#<?php echo get_the_title();?"> <?php echo get_the_title();?>  </a>
```

It could be great if it automatically translate it to

```
 bla&nbsp;bla
```

so I'll have

```
 href=#bla&nbsp;bla.
```

I hope you understand what I'm struggling with for now the only option is to put in the page title

```
bla&nbsp;bla
```

Here is my loop it's a menu in a page calling sub-pages:

```
 <?php 

$args = array (
    'posts_per_page' => -1, //Showing all the pages
    'post_type' =>  'page', //Retrieving pages not posts.
    'post_parent'   => $post->ID,
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC'

    );

$the_query = new WP_query($args);
while($the_query->have_posts()):
    $the_query->the_post();
        if ($the_query->current_post == 0){ ?>

         <li class="active"> <a href="#<?php echo get_the_title();?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a> </li>


      <?php  }
        else{   ?>

  <li>  <a href="#<?php echo get_the_title();?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a> </li>


  <?php }
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Core functions [`the_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink#Description), and [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink#Description) are built to do what you are trying to hack together manually. Those will provide a complete URL for the link.

What you are doing would at best be a relative link, which is problematic, and there is no guarantee that the title would match the URL anyway. Permalinks are transformed in several different ways, they are manually editable, and are also forced to be unique by the addition of appendixes if necessary.

Edit:

To create internal links, all you need are unique identifiers. There are a couple of ways to do that without straying far from core code.

```
<a  href="#<?php echo sanitize_title_with_dashes(get_the_title()); ?>"> 
  <?php echo get_the_title();?>  
</a>
```

[`sanitize_title_with_dashes()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes#Description) is the function used by the Core in the conversion of the title to the post slug.

This means that within a Loop, you can use the post slug itself for much the same effect.

```
<a  href="#<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"> 
  <?php echo get_the_title();?>  
</a>
```

Comment: Hi I know about the permalink but the problem is that I'm making a page with a menu listing sub-pages and displaying their content on click on the right

Comment: @Max : see the edit

Answer (score 0):

HTML tag class or id property can't have non alpha-numeric value, so you rather need to sanitize the title to create a proper one. You could use `sanitize_html_class` to do that. Or for a relative sanitization, you could use the below one.

```
function wpse_sanitize_html_class( $class ){
    //Strip out any % encoded octets
    $sanitized = preg_replace( '|%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]|', '', $class );

    //Limit to A-Z,a-z,0-9,_,-
    $sanitized = preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/', '-', $sanitized );

    return $sanitized;
}
```

Using it on your production -

```
<a  href="#<?php 
    echo wpse_sanitize_html_class( get_the_title() ); ?>"><?php 
    echo get_the_title();?>
</a>
```

And the content wrapper element, the id property will need to be sanitized too.

```
<div id="<?php 
    echo wpse_sanitize_html_class( get_the_title() );?>"><?php 
    // the content  ?>
</div>
```

### Simple Solution

Simple solution could be using post id rather than title. Like this -

```
<a  href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>
<div id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php // the content  ?></div>
```